# why this regular expression returns empty

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I have these strings:
`Phone: 3396222`
`Phone: +33333388`

I want to extract the numbers.

I tried this regular expression:

```
Phone:\s*(\d+\.\d+)
```

#### But I got an empty result

I am using scrapy so my code is like this: `sel.xpath(..).re(..)`

#### please don't suggest using other feature in python than regular expression

Comment: You don't have a `.` in your string.

Comment: I found the solution myself, I should have used this `Phone:\s*(\d+)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression *requires* a `.` dot in the text, but your sample input has none.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'Phone:\s*(\d+\.\d+)', 'Phone: 3396222') is None
True
>>> re.search(r'Phone:\s*(\d+\.\d+)', 'Phone: 339.6222').group(1)
'339.6222'
```

If you wanted to make either of your sample phone numbers match, remove the `\.` (instead adding it to a character set) and add an optional `+` to the expression:

```
r'Phone:\s*(\+?[\d.]+)'
```

Demo:

```
>>> re.search(r'Phone:\s*(\+?[\d.]+)', 'Phone: 3396222').group(1)
'3396222'
>>> re.search(r'Phone:\s*(\+?[\d.]+)', 'Phone: +33333388').group(1)
'+33333388'
```

This pattern also allows for any number of dots in the number:

```
>>> re.search(r'Phone:\s*(\+?[\d.]+)', 'Phone: +333.333.88').group(1)
'+333.333.88'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for mandatory dot(.) inside your regex. Mate it optional:

```
Phone:\s*\+?(\d+\.?\d+)
         ^^^      ^
```

I have updated by adding optional `\+` as you added `+` in your input.